# WP7: sending images to twitter

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

How to implement sending images to some application in Windows Phone 7?
In the Android it's done via Intents.

Comment: em? you want to send img to twitter or to app? You maight want to look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402558%28VS.92%29.aspx

Comment: I want to send image to twitter application on Windows Phone or send to Windows Phone album or send by MMS. It depends on user wishes and installed programs. Thanks for link, I will try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 does not support communication between apps or shared files so as a general rule you can't. There is currenlty no equivalent to androids Intents in WP7.

With regard to an application which works with images you could create a [Photo Extras Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817010%28VS.92%29.aspx) to work with images already on the device.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, take a look at [this article](http://dennisdel.com/?p=478). Once you get the image, all you have to do is use a service like TwitPic to post it there (an example for the v1.0 API is [shown here](http://dennisdel.com/?p=164)).